# Spring Batch How to set time interval between each call in a Chunk tasklet

Tags: java, batch-processing, spring-batch

Team,

I am doing a technical poc for reading records from a flat file and inserting the data to database.

I am using chunk task and running this job using spring batch admin successfully.

I have to implement the retry policy along with a feature to set the time interval between each retry. I am stuck up with setting the time interval between each retry as chuck doesn't support it directly. Is there any work around for this?

My code is

```
<batch:job id="importDataJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
  <batch:step id="importDataStep">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
      <batch:chunk reader="dataReader" writer="dataWriter"  commit-interval="1" retry-limit="3">
        <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
          <batch:include class="javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException" />
        </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
      </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: you will need to define the retry-policy and backoff policy to set the interval. By default spring only allow to set retry attempts.
Refer this link for more help
http://www.javabeat.net/articles/309-configure-spring-batch-to-retrying-on-error-1.html

Comment: also refer to this one for backoff-policy http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?118637-How-to-specify-interval-between-successive-retry-attempts

Comment: @Kshitij : Thanks for the link Kshitij. I thought about the same , but there is no option to set the backoff policy with chunk.

Comment: you will need to create a RetryTemplate where in you can configure backoffpolicy. Of what i know is you will need to create your own ItemWriter and the ReptryTemplate will be wired inside it and will than use a callback method. See this link for more details http://books.google.co.in/books?id=A0eOJHOkpKEC&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=spring+batch+%22retryTemplate%22&source=bl&ots=lvfhm8PZN8&sig=2xsYHuwWdfirE_nZjE9rwpJ9O8k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9ISaT5_TDIOJrAf37fyrDg&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=spring%20batch%20%22retryTemplate%22&f=false However, an importnt page is missing in the link.Its upto u to find it.

Comment: @Kshitij : I want the retry functionality not only in writer , but in my reader also. I am googling the same for last one week and have gone through almost all possible search results. So please don't post google search links. But I would like to appreciate your attitude and effort to support. I even thought about moving out of chunk and writing my own tasklet (Any way I don't need chunk processing, I have put the chunk size as 1). But in that approach I may have to handle the restarting features in the code. :(

Comment: I'm wishing for a way to cause a delay outside of retries. Just delaying between chunks even when they're succeeding. (To not overwhelm an external system.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case the configuration will look like:

**Spring Batch 2.x**

```
<bean id="stepParent" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean" abstract="true">
  <property name="backOffPolicy">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.retry.backoff.FixedBackOffPolicy"
      <property name="backOffPeriod" value="2000" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<batch:job id="importDataJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
  <batch:step id="importDataStep" parent="stepParent">
     ...
  </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Unfortunately, `batch` namespace does not support setting `backOffPolicy` directly to `step`, see [BATCH-1441](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-1441).

**Spring Batch 3.0**

In Spring Batch 3.0 some classes have moved to other packages. This is the the configuration fragment:

```
<bean id="stepParent"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.factory.FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean"         
  abstract="true">

  <property name="backOffPolicy">
    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.FixedBackOffPolicy">
      <property name="backOffPeriod" value="2000"/>
    </bean>
  </property>

</bean>
```

Comment: Should be <property name="backOffPeriod" value="2000" />