# Process a single big text file using partitioning and asynchronous task executor in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

How can I process a single big text file using partitioning and asynchronous task executor in spring batch?

i have tried by using attribute in spring batch grid-size=10. but all the records are processing 10 times.

Comment: Also, your title and the question where the exact same sentence, this unfortunately leaves the impression that you didn't put any effort into this. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i re-framed my question.

Comment: this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672776/spring-batch-multithreaded-processing-for-single-file-to-multiple-file